# Firefox on Ubuntu: Network Monitor selects multiple requests

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

Firefox network monitor is behaving in a way I do not understand.  Sometimes, when I select a network request in the dev tools, it selects multiple (seemingly random) other requests as well.  Details from only one of the requests are shown on the details pane (again, seemingly random as to which request's details).  It also seems to "forget" to display the return status codes, even though the requests DO complete.

[Screenshot (I've only selected 1 network request)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0mk6.png)

It's been doing this for weeks, and now it's critically impacting my ability to move forward on a Vue project I'm working on.  Multiple Google searches have turned up nothing.  Have I found a bug in FF, or is this expected behavior that I'm misinterpreting?

Ubuntu 20.04
Firefox 79.0 (also occurred in previous versions)

Comment: Same thing here: selecting one request marks 3 different requests as selected, meaning that I can only see the request/response data from one of the requests :/ Firefox 80 on Ubuntu 20.04